# Process Builder To Notify Teams When Approved Applications Are Less Than A Certain Figure

Tags: process-builder, process

Is it possible to use Process builder to notify users that Applications are less/more than a certain number by a particular time of that day?
Example - Object is "Applications"

Id like to notify two team members about the number of Approved Applications received by 12pm on that given day, and then repeat the process to update them at 5pm.

What would be the steps neccessary?
Thanks

Comment: In what way would you like to notify those team members? Email/Task/Popup etc..

Comment: The [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/business_process_automation/units/process_builder) will give you a better understanding on what and how to use the process builder.

Comment: Hi @JaredT
I have sms ability within my org, so that could be utilised. Im open to suggestions :)

Comment: Not sure of the SMS solution you are using but at worst it should have an accessible API which you can use in an Apex class that is run via trigger or Process Builder

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the exact methods by which you want to notify the team members it should absolutely be possible; this is basic functionality of the Process Builder (or even Workflow Rules) that you can learn more about on Trailhead:

Process Automation on Trailhead:
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/business_process_automation

The process builder allows you to build simple-to-moderately-complicated triggers (with some limitations). For your purpose the Process could be fired when the "Application" object is created/is updated to meet the criteria "Field is equal to 'Approved'", and specify the action to take once that criteria is met.

The action you specify can be simple, such as sending an email (you will need to create an email alert and accompanying email template), it can update other records (which can then go on to trigger their own automation actions, or recursively trigger further automation on the same record), or it can run a custom Apex class.

If you are going the relatively simpler route, an email alert, you will specify the recipients within the customization of the email alert itself - the alerts are not specific to the process and can be re-used by other pieces of automation.

Comment: added more info and some examples